# Tabs buttons inside fragment ,How to achieve it?

Tags: java, android

problems:

- tabs width.

> **as you see in my design (Figma) i have two buttons have two different fragments , i used tablayout with viewpager and indicator , it works but the design i got isn't as i excepted, the tabs it was too big in width ,i tried to fix it but it got worst :(**

the XML code(house_fragment.XML):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".HouseFragment"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->


        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="32dp"
            android:clipToPadding="false">

            <View
                android:id="@+id/indicator"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:background="@drawable/gradient_tab"/>

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:background="@drawable/tab_bg"
                app:tabGravity="fill"
                app:tabMode="fixed"
                app:tabSelectedTextColor="#ffffff"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="@null"
                app:tabRippleColor="@null"/>

        </FrameLayout>

        <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewPager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:ignore="MissingClass" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

java code(house_fragment.java):

```
    TabLayout mTabs;
    View mIndicator;
    ViewPager mViewPager;

    private int indicatorWidth;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_farm, container, false);
        //Assign view reference
        mTabs = view.findViewById(R.id.tab);
        mIndicator = view.findViewById(R.id.indicator);
        mViewPager = view.findViewById(R.id.viewPager);

        //Set up the view pager and fragments
        TabFragmentAdapter adapter = new TabFragmentAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(info_fragment.newInstance("param1", "param2"), "Info");
        adapter.addFragment(stat_fragment.newInstance("param1", "param2"), "Statistic");
        mViewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        mTabs.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
        //Determine indicator width at runtime
        mTabs.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                indicatorWidth = mTabs.getWidth() / mTabs.getTabCount();

                //Assign new width
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams indicatorParams = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) mIndicator.getLayoutParams();
                indicatorParams.width = indicatorWidth;
                mIndicator.setLayoutParams(indicatorParams);
            }
        });

        mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            //To move the indicator as the user scroll, we will need the scroll offset values
            //positionOffset is a value from [0..1] which represents how far the page has been scrolled
      
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int i, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPx) {
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams)mIndicator.getLayoutParams();

                //Multiply positionOffset with indicatorWidth to get translation
                float translationOffset =  (positionOffset+i) * indicatorWidth ;
                params.leftMargin = (int) translationOffset;
                mIndicator.setLayoutParams(params);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int i) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int i) {

            }
        });

        return view;
    }
```

and the adapter for fragments(TabFragmentAdapter):

```
public class TabFragmentAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> fragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> fragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public TabFragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }


    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        return fragmentList.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fragmentList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return fragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        fragmentList.add(fragment);
        fragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }
}
```

**is there's another solution that allows me to set width that i want**

**the exception :
[Statistic selected button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JisOD.png)
[Info selected button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2gKH.png)
the result :
[result i got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EAzJe.png)**